# Magento Manage Categories page broken

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

I suddenly started encountering this problem out of nowhere. My 'Manage Categories' page is broken and looks something like this. [image: screenshot of broken 'manage categories' page]

Also when I tried uploading new images for my products using 'Manage Products' section it just kept loading and never really upoaded the image. I am guessing both the issues are related.

I uploaded my design adminhtml and skin adminhtml files. I also saw on a forum that Apache server's broken/corrupt file can cause this problem, hence re uploaded the js folder too, but to no success.

Has any one got any idea on how to fix this problem, I would really appreciate it.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem can be the AdminHTML template or the old compiled AdminHTML template in the cache. Try to restore the original AdminHTML template and let me know!

Regards

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I am sorry what do you mean by try to restore the original AdminHTML template?

Comment: How do u check for magic quotes now? And can that affect the styling of this page?

Comment: @ivn copy the Admin folder from the original project structure previously downloaded from magentocommerce.com. Remember to select the right release.

Comment: @Mikunos Thanks a ton!! I deleted n re uploaded app/code/core/Mage/Admin n app/code/core/Mage Adminhtml folders from a fresh downloaded version of Magento 1.6.1.0 (thats d version m using) from magentocommerce.com and worked like a charm. :) So m guessing it was a matter of broken/corrupt files in the cache with old Admin template. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Mikunos As weird as it may sound, your solution worked perfectly fine, but I have got another blank page problem. On my front end, the product category pages show up fine but when ever I click on any product, the product view page shows blank. Any ideas now why this is happening? sorry to bother u again, but I am tired of these unexpected problems as well.

Comment: @ivn if the page is blank you have to check the log file in your Apache log directory. Let me know what the apache has written in the log file.

Comment: @Mikunos If u talking about var/log/system.log file then it shows a lot of warnings which mostly corresponds to this line '2011-12-07T11:46:02+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string() [<a href='function.simplexml-load-string'>function.simplexml-load-string</a>]: Entity: line 1: parser error : XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document  in /home/wpfsl/public_html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510'

Comment: @Mikunos Sorry again, but I think I found it.I viewed the page source for my product view page and saw that it was giving me some PageCache/Helper/Data error. I just deleted n reloaded app/code/core/Mage/PageCache and it worked fine !! :)

Answer (score 2):

Seems you are using git on windows. I had same. It was crlf trouble. Git converts line breaks. Use autocrlf as false for git and reclone your repo.

Answer (score 1):

If there is content before the doctype header...

```
<div>break stuff</div>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

It will cause this.

Answer (score 0):

hazzah, I found what went wrong with my category page.

Go to your index.php file in your magento root folder. Uncomment #ini_set('display_errors', 1); By removing the #.

After that go to your manage categories page, there should be a list of the error. Navigate to the php file that it list and if it lists a Class assume the _ are / to get to the class it requires.

Mine turned out to be /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Tree.php and
/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Tabs.php were blank.

Copy them from one of your other installations of Magento(everyone else has 50 right?) or you can find it in the Magento installation zip file.

Good luck

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer that is your magento some js files was crashed but I can't find what files that are. my advice is in **magento\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\catalog\category\edit.phtml**. Open this file and search for this line

```
catch (e) {
  alert(e.message);
};
```

In the update function and comment this lines and refresh your magento admin page you don't get this error anymore. And also after you add a category click on save category button and click f5 for page refresh then your category will be add. This is the only way I found.

Note be careful when you add a category. You can't edit after adding.

Comment: Are you sure that the advice to remove the error message is correct?